# JavaFX: How can I change the points of a polygon in an animation?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I know that you can change the position of a circle in an animation like this (see also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/animation.htm)):

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, // set start position at 0
        new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
        new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)
    ),
    new KeyFrame(new Duration(40000), // set end position at 40s
        new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
        new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)
    )
);
```

But is there also a possibility (this means a `Property`) to change the points of a polygon in an animation?

And if not: Which other possibilities do I have to morph a polygon in an animation using JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no individual properties of the points in a `Polygon`, but you could us a `Path` of `LineTo`s, `MoveTo` and `ClosePath` to animate the coordinates of a polygon individually.

**Example:**

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setPrefSize(400, 400);

MoveTo corner1 = new MoveTo();
LineTo corner2 = new LineTo();
LineTo corner3 = new LineTo();

Path path = new Path(corner1, corner2, corner3, new ClosePath());
pane.getChildren().add(path);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                new KeyValue(corner1.xProperty(), 200d),
                new KeyValue(corner1.yProperty(), 200d),
                new KeyValue(corner2.xProperty(), 200d),
                new KeyValue(corner2.yProperty(), 200d),
                new KeyValue(corner3.xProperty(), 200d),
                new KeyValue(corner3.yProperty(), 200d)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),
                new KeyValue(corner1.xProperty(), 100d),
                new KeyValue(corner1.yProperty(), 100d),
                new KeyValue(corner2.xProperty(), 250d),
                new KeyValue(corner2.yProperty(), 300d),
                new KeyValue(corner3.xProperty(), 50d),
                new KeyValue(corner3.yProperty(), 380d)));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
timeline.play();
```